# Single Digits From String In Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, split

Given a string

```
1 3 2 1 9 1 bla 3 4 3
```

I found that

```
/b[1-4]/b
```

will return only the digits `1 2 3 4` as [this](https://regex101.com/r/WaNxyD/1/) shows but `String[] input = args[0].split("\b[1-4]\b");` does not return

```
{"1","3","2","1","1","3","4","3"}
```

Comment: So what should `1 3 23 1 9 1 bla92 3 4 3` produce?

Comment: "1 3 1 1 3 4 3"

Comment: Just match with `"\\b[1-4]\\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I've learnt so much about regex patterns from your posts. Just curious if `[1-4]` is not enough? If not, what problems can arise if I use just `[1-4]`?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Sorry, I just used OP pattern, but fixed the backslashes issue. OP seems to have used `\b[1-4]\b` regex to match `1`, `2`, `3` or `4` as whole words, i.e. only when they are not enclosed with other digits, letters or underscores. No idea if it is really what OP needs. One thing is sure: `String#split` does not work the same way as `Matcher#find` and that is the main issue.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew for explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that you are trying to split on the numbers themselves.  This won't give the intended result, because that on which you split gets *consumed* (read: removed), leaving behind everything else.  Instead, try splitting on `[^1-4]+`:

```
String input = "1 3 2 1 9 1 bla 3 4 3";
String[] parts = input.split("[^1-4]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3]
```

This will split on one or more non 1-4 characters.  This happens to work for your input string, because whitespace is a delimiter, and also the non matching digits and words should be removed.

Comment: @JvdV Good catch.  I have made an edit, which should work assuming the numbers present would always be 0-9.

Comment: That's quite a dangerous assumption but then again, nothing to proof otherwise =)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you only want digits between 1 and 4. A simple split is not going to be enough. One approach could be something like this:

```
String str = "1 3 2 1 9 1 bla 3 4 3";
String[] splitAndFilter = Pattern.compile("\\s+")
                                 .splitAsStream(str)
                                 .filter(s -> s.matches("[1-4]"))
                                 .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitAndFilter));
```

Comment: I guess this is nice to remove unwanted subpatterns from text like `bla-4-bla` (if such thing would ever occur)

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `[1-4]` as the regex.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] matches = Pattern.compile("[1-4]")
                .matcher(args[0])
                .results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matches));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3]
```

where the command-line argument is `"1 3 2 1 9 1 bla 3 4 3"`